# Conditionally require authentication to access route in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authorization

In Laravel 5.4 I have a Page model and I would like to add a new field in DB to conditionally require authentication to browse the page.

So basically I want to serve pages, some pages will be accessible to everybody and some pages will require the user to be authenticated. If the user needs to be authenticated to view the page, he then will be redirected to the login page.

How can I implement this in Laravel?

I am thinking [Gate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization) but i am unsure how to mix both unauthenticated and authenticated rules..

Thanks guys!

EDIT
I found a way to achieve what i want by doind so in my `PageController`:

```
public function index($id)
{
    $page = Page::findOrFail($id);

    if ($page->require_auth && !Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }

    return view('page', compact('page'));
}
```

But i am still not sure this is the best place to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some page restrict to authenticated users, you can use the default auth middleware.

To use the default one, run:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

This will create:

- Login View
- Remember password View
- "Register" View
- AuthController
- Routes to each view + "actions"

Then, you can simply use "middleware:auth" (check: app/Http/Kernel.php to see all middlewares).

OR, you can simple create your own middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware MyAuthMiddleware ## This generate a new middleware file inside app/Http/Middleware
```

You can do:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class MyAuthMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!auth()->check()) {
            abort(403, 'Access denied');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

After that, just add a reference to this class into Kernel.php (app/Http/Kernel.php).

```
<?php

// ....
protected $routeMiddleware = [
 'my-auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyAuthMiddleware::class
];
```

More info about middlewares: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

Comment: This would add auth to the route that serve all pages, how can i apply it conditionally? Only for page that have a "require_auth" boolean set to true in DB for instance

Comment: I think i need to write my own middleware, but i would like to handle this nicely: the user should be redirected to login page, and if login is successful he should be redirected to the originally intended page. this is how the default auth middleware works.